# Alternator and voltage regulator recommendation(s) for antique engine based 12V power source

Tags: batteries, charging, rpm

What would be good hardware to provide 12V DC for battery bank charging driven by an antique stationary engine that does not run at a steady RPM?

These old engines can run on practically any liquid that will burn but it's very difficult to get one to run at a steady pace.  I have a 7HP engine that runs at a couple of hundred rpm.  Torque output is massive due to a very long stroke so it can be geared up to run an alternator or generator at a much higher RPM.

Comment: Might be a good match for a wind turbine generator in the 5 kW range.

Comment: You may wish to consider multiple alternators at 12V.  You control the field coil as speed changes to keep voltage output steady.  You may also wish to consider a different battery voltage.  If your engine provides 7HP, 7*746W/HP=5222W.  At 12V, 5222W provides 5222W/12V=435A!.  You likely won't use close to the full capacity of the generator, but doubling output voltage will halve output current, so if you can consider 24V or 48V, now is the time to do so.  At 48V, you're still dealing with a potential ~110A so you may need #3 wire or larger.

Answer (score 2):

Use a large pulley on the crankshaft to get the altenator speed up-to 2000 RPM or so. Then just use a commodity automotive alternator. (eg from a automotive recycler, or an off-ther shelf aftermarket one)

Most automotive alternators have the regulator built in, but if not regulators can be had from most auto-parts stores.

If this is for a boat, use a brushless alternator.

Comment: If it's to charge car batteries, a car alternator makes sens to me. Doesn't have to be 12V exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Lister-type engine by any chance? Lots of choices to be had - it’s a popular alt-energy source.

Example: https://www.otherpower.com/fuking.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm just answering to echo the "Use a COTS alternator" advice more specifically.

### Use a modern, competent COTS alternator

The best source is a "pick-n-pull" yard so you can pick from a specific model that you have researched, and you can easily grab all relevant wiring harnesses.  Walking up to a full-service they-pull-em scrapyard won't get you the harness, and (in case you've never fixed a car) auto parts stores don't sell harnesses or connectors. (well, they sell *a few* connectors, mostly quite old domestic stock).

Focus on the car makes that are common as dirt in your country; avoid legacy Euro if you can (their volume is too low, they can't mount the R&D resources to get it right).

1. Use an *internal regulator* alternator of recent make and model.  They are best calibrated to charge a battery accurately (despite high hotel loads) - after all they must work with sealed AGM batteries like Optima Red Tops.  Mucking about with 1950s era external regulators is a waste of time.
2. Seriously consider a 1-wire alternator.  A 1-wire alternator is dog simple: Attach battery hot to it and yer done.   However, the 1-wire alternator is incapable of being switched off.

Most automotive alternators are 3-wire, which is perfectly fine if you're willing to hunker down and get the documentation for the donor vehicle and figure out how to wire it up.  As an example, I've seen the other 2 wires be this:

- +12V for "please Generate" (hooked to ignition switch hot-in-run).  Hot-in-run is de-energized during engine start, and that avoids a race condition where the starter is burdened with alternator load as the alternator tries to provide current to the starter, a vicious circle obviously.
- Field current limiter - wired through a fusible link or fuse to either hot or ground, this prevents the alternator from starting an engine fire if the regulator fails "hard-on" and maxes out field current.

If you don't set up the alternator correctly, it will "bog" the small engine so much it will never get up to target RPM.  That is best handled by prudent selection of **gearing**.

### Now, if you're trying to *also regulate the engine speed*...

That's gonna be a big problem.  You may think "Oh, I can use selective regulation of the alternator to control RPM by controlling load"... **nope**. If your hotel loads are low, and your battery is full up, *the alternator has no place to send that excess power*.

You could  have a second, external-regulator alternator driving into a resistor bank, but now you're just wasting fuel.

You need to figure out how to put an actuator on the fuel rack of this machine.  (fuel rack because I assume it's diesel).

If the engine is not externally governed, you might consider an Arduino with an RPM sensor, and a couple of solenoids to pull the rack.  Remember your freewheeling diodes on those big solenoids!  You could borrow a page from EMD's 567 type engine, and have a swashplate or lever acted upon by 2-4 solenoids.  Imagine a bar with the rack control in the middle; solenoid 0 pulls the left edge of the bar 2X distance, and the solenoid 1 pulls the right edge 4X distance.

```
  solenoid 1    solenoid 0   center distance
      0             0              0
      0             1              x
      1             0              2x
      1             1              3x
```

Looky that, plain old binary code.

You could do something more clever with the linkage to have the same effect, e.g. offset the center to the 1/3 point and make each solenoid travel the same.

A proper EMD implementation uses 4 solenoids, one of which adds a negative value, allowing selection of 0-8X and also shutdown.  Of course, EMD controls an *RPM governor* which actually operates rack; even if you selected 1101 (with the 0 being the negative solenoid) you will not smoke the engine.  You're running bare naked; if your Arduino crashes and selects all solenoids on, rack goes to 100% and the engine explodes.

You could also try the General Motors Rochester carburetor approach from the 1970s, and have 1 channel that you PWM..  I would take the extra effort to PWM a shaped AC signal out to a transformer, creating a variable voltage AC on the other side of the transformer.  Why?  Because if the Arduino crashes on hard "1", it will output DC. DC will not go through a transformer. This will idle the engine instead of send it into runaway.